# How to prevent someone from logging in into Ubuntu without knowing the password?

Tags: 18.04, login, security, login-screen, privacy

I just had my browser tabs changed when I just logged in today, it was Incognito so I can't tell if I can go back to it, but I'm very confused as to how can someone logged in to my computer without knowing the password. I had many incidents where when I logged in, something has changed even though I'm pretty sure no one can tell the password. I need help as to prevent someone from logging in physically, because right now, I can't prevent it by moving to a different place because of my circumstances.

Comment: Well, there's fingerprint scanners you can buy online and set that up for logging in, although can't suggest a resource on that topic. Check also `last` and `lastb` logs, check  `/var/log/auth.log`, it may show timestamps and attempts to log in, so if you find nothing between the times you weren't at the machine - there's two possibilities, altered logs or it's not a person who logged into computer, but maybe you have automatic process that cleans up users directory and removed Chrome cache/configs.

Comment: Question, how can one alter the logs? All I see in clearing up logs is that you delete the whole thing, not delete a few things. Also I did not set up Chrome cache clean ups, there were times that when I logged in, nothing has changed there.

Comment: Well, logs are just a text file ( in some cases - binary files, but mostly text). So if they have access to your account and you're `sudo` user -  it's just as simple as invoking a text editor with `sudo` and deleting couple lines, or even `sed` or other tool.

Comment: How do I prevent that? Also is there any way I can tell if the logs where altered? Like some sort of command that tells me if something has changed?

Comment: Technically, yes, you could look at the modification time reported by `stat /var/log/auth.log` for example. But if you logged in with `sudo` *after* the file was changed, your record will be added and modification timestamp will refer to the time you signed in with `sudo`. So, really depends and one has to proceed carefully

Comment: I should have also mentioned that someone has logged in to bypass the lockscreen.

Comment: Start by at least changing your password. Then consider if there's any keyloggers installed on the machine. If it's a workplace - consider contacting your IT department and see if they can do something about it, investigate who it could be.

Comment: Yes, lockscreen can be bypassed via one of the TTYs. If possible, consider switching to another desktop environment and desktop manager, because there is a bug in GDM which can show typed-in password in console: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1767918

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you at install time you did not tick the box to allow login without password?

If so, no wonder others can login without a password.

Otherwise, someone else still can login to your machine without a password, using a live USB and then read/tamper watever files that s/he wishes.

But if you are sure that your browser history has been change, so very probably the intruder does in fact KNOW your password or the login does not require a password. So either change your password or go change the settings to requre password for login.

But please notice that if:

1. The physical access to your unintended hard disk is possible
2. Your hard disk is not encrypted

your data can not be 100% secure.

An unintended, unencrypted disk is an easy target for anyone with a minimum linux knowledge and a live USB.